# Execution time Cloudera VM

Tags: hadoop, virtual-machine, cloudera, hue

I'm using a Cloudera VM with the standard configuration, and when I execute predefined examples execution time is quite long. Are there any configuration to set to improve the execution time?

Comment: can you be more specific: what/how examples are you running and what do you mean by quite long?

Comment: I have a macbook pro (Intel Core i5, 8GB RAM) and I'm using the Oracle VM VirtualBox, Linux 2.6/3.x (64bit), 5013 MB RAM, 1 CPU. For example, the execution time of "UpperText(example)" (Pig example) is about 2 minutes. All the examples on Hive have an execution time of about 40 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding more memory and CPU cores to the VM.